# HttpClient: Which exception will be thrown when server is down

Tags: android, httpclient

Im wondering which exception will be thrown in apache HttpClient (Android) if the webserver is down (because of heavy trafic etc.) and can therefore not deliver a correct http response for my http request.

Is that a simple SocketTimeoutException or something else?

I would like to ensure, that my app can handle server down scenarios, by displaying a simple message that the server may be down.

Comment: Why don't you try it? I would be very interested in knowing the answer.

Comment: i think SocketTimeoutException will be thrown if server is down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException

java.io.IOException
  +- org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException
```

In some circumstances, usually when under heavy load, the web server may be able to receive requests but unable to process them. A lack of sufficient resources like worker threads is a good example. This may cause the server to drop the connection to the client without giving any response. `HttpClient` throws `NoHttpResponseException` when it encounters such a condition. In most cases it is safe to retry a method that failed with `NoHttpResponseException`.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html

Comment: NoHttpResponseException: "In some circumstances, usually when under heavy load, the web server may be able to receive requests but unable to process them", says the docs about NoHttpResponseException. So it seems to be the right way. Have you got some negative experience with that exception type @Selvin

Comment: I could not test it at all, but this one seems to be the exception I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be an `IOException`